# Application Specific Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am creating a program that searches a folder and catalogs all the files it finds in a database. I know how to create a localhost database (or one hosted on a web) and connect to that. But that would require anyone who I give this app to, to have set up their own database.

I would like to be able to have a specific database created for only this application, that lives in the same root folder with the application and can be moved from computer to computer (preferably MySQL). Is this possible?

Comment: If you want everything to live in the same folder, why are you using a database in the first place, instead of just persisting your data to flat files?

Comment: because mysql is fast and has nice functions for searching and sorting. (and I'm a noob)

Comment: Well, it's certainly possible to do a scripted MySQL install and then invoke it from whatever application installer you're using, but I think you're making a lot of extra work for yourself with this design.

Comment: You might be able embed a database (like Apache Derby) into your application

Comment: I agree with @vandale, if you want database functionality, using an [embedded Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html) database would be much cleaner than trying to use an external database.

Comment: You probably want an embedded database. [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) is not as capable as MySQL but it does a great job if you need something simple and reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I need is an Embedded database (Apache Derby, SQLite). Thanks guys in the comments!